# Intellij build scala module showing error with scalac:Error:scala/xml/MetaData

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

I have a scala project that I just imported into my intelliJ IDE. When I click on build module, i notice the below error showing up.

I am running scala sdk 2.12.6

```
Error:scalac: Error: scala/xml/MetaData
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/xml/MetaData
    at com.sksamuel.scapegoat.io.IOUtils$.writeXMLReport(IOUtils.scala:29)
    at com.sksamuel.scapegoat.ScapegoatComponent$$anon$1.run(plugin.scala:179)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1446)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1430)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:1423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1539)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:130)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:105)
    at xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.scala:31)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:237)
    at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:111)
    at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:90)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.IdeaIncrementalCompiler.compile(IdeaIncrementalCompiler.scala:42)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.compile(LocalServer.scala:43)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.compileLogic(Main.scala:117)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.handleCommand(Main.scala:109)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.serverLogic(Main.scala:95)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.nailMain(Main.scala:53)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main.nailMain(Main.scala)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:319)
```

Comment: Have you seen the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30049797/4993128)?

Comment: @jwvh Yes. The cause is very different. My project is a scala project and it has all the dependency ever needed for that scapegoat to run.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that if I just run `mvn package` i don't see such build errors at all.

Something to do with intelliJ IDE where when I right click project and click on "build". It may not be doing all the stuff that maven is doing therefore is throwing that error.

Comment: Wow can't believe I see you comment